# Adding zipped source to Eclipse without extracting it first

Tags: eclipse

I have a Java project in Eclipse, and some external zip file with additional source.
I would like to use the zip as an external library, i.e. that it would be built along with the project and that I could see the code in the IDE (at least read-only).

Is this possible?

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't have a library jar file to which I could attach the source.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible because Eclipse Unzip .zip files in the import! To use a library use a .jar library!

Compile your zip file to a jar file and you don't have any problem!